# Golang Postgres repeatable read isolation level is not working

Tags: postgresql, go, transactions, isolation-level, acid

My understanding of the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level is that once it is set, the data read through in the transaction will not change. I have used the following code to verify this:

```
ctx = context.Background()
tx, _ := db.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelSerializable}) 
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
// do query on tx
```

While the process is sleeping,  I have inserted another record through the console. But the newly inserted record has appeared in the results. Why is that so? I don't want to read the records which are inserted after the transaction has begun. I also tried:

```
tx, _ := db.Begin()
_, err = tx.Exec(`set transaction isolation level repeatable read;`)
```

But still the results are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snapshot of a `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` transaction is not taken at the time when the transaction is started, but when the first SQL statement runs inside the transaction.

First, this is an optimization for the case that the transaction does not run any statement at all. Second, it is the only way to allow setting the transaction isolation level *after* the start of the transaction, but *before* any SQL statement has been run with

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Comment: I'd expect that to be `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, which sets the isolation level right when the transaction is started.